# How to get an attribute on the ancestor axis in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml:

```
<msg id="abc" type="test">
  <local id="def"/>
  <cnts x:type="fld" id="111" type="a2">
  </cnts>
</msg>
```

The xslt is:

```
<xsl:template match="contents[@x:type='fld']">
  <xsl:variable name="msgs">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestoer::msg">
      <msg><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></msg>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

I expect the output would be:

```
<msg>test</msg>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Could someone help please?

Comment: The input XML has an element `cnts` which isn't the same as `contents` as in XSLT. Why would you do that? Update the XML to be complete. Having a variable to store some value doesn't output it, show us your complete XSLT!! And, the axis is spelled `ancestor`!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your XSLT and your XML, each of which may or may not be the cause of your issue:

1. Your XSLT is not complete, you probably did this to save space, but it makes it harder to guess what is wrong (namespace bindings, apply-templates etc)
2. Your XML does not match your XSLT, as mentioned in the comments, the template matches an element `contents` which is not in your XML (did you mean `cnts`?).
3. Your snippet, even if wrapped inside a valid `xsl:stylesheet` element, cannot possibly compile, `ancestoer::msg` will raise a compile time (static) error.
4. Your snippet defines a variable, but does not use it, hence whatever is in your variable will not be visible.
5. You seem to want to loop over the ancestor axis, which could select multiple elements `msg`, not sure this is intentional

If all of the above are correct in your actual XSLT, then your issue lies somewhere else and we will have to see more of your XSLT *and* XML, in fact, we'll need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That said, here are three ways of using the ancestor axis:

1. If you only want one item, you do not need the intermediate variable and you can simply use `<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::msg/@type" />`.
2. If you want to loop over all ancestors, you can use:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="contents[@x:type='fld']">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::msg" mode="anc" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="msg" mode="anc">
       <msg><xsl:value-of select="@type" /></msg>
   </xsl:message>
   ```

   In this example, I deliberately switch modes, because there is a good chance you may be matching on `msg` somewhere else already, in which case you may end up in an never-ending loop.
3. Your current approach with `xsl:for-each`. This is not wrong, just less flexible and in the long run more typing. The use of the variable is not needed, but if you want to use a variable, just make sure you also use it, for instance with `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: I changed the attribute name at the last moment and forgot to change it in the xslts. The variable in xslt is indeed used somewhere else. Thanks for the answer Abel!